# Approving a previously declined access request

Tags: permissions, access-denied

I have a user that previously had an access request denied. In his new role, he now needs access, but I cannot reopen the previously declined request, and he cannot submit a new request. He gets the default "Access has been Denied" message. Any solution? This is in Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Is the access request still turned on? (Under Site Permissions and the Manage Access Requests)

Comment: Yes - the 'allow access requests' box is checked.  I've sent the individual the link to the home page thinking that he could just request access again, but he gets the 'Access has been denied' pop up.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what level of permission the user should have now in his new role, I would suggest adding him to the applicable group in the site's permissions scheme. If you and/or he are unsure what level of permissions that the access request would grant him by default, I would reference previous access requests for your site and view what permission level has been approved there (the default group's permission level will commonly be referenced in the request - see screenshot).

Granting applicable access this way will likely save you and he the time of attempting to recreate or correct the original access request.

[image]

Cheers,

-Drew